# Drawing vertices and edges of a graph in excel

Tags: excel, windows, ms-office

Suppose I have the following 2 columns in Microsoft excel:

```
1 2
3 4
2 5
3 6
```

Here each element of first column represents a node and 2nd column represents another node. In the above example, there are 6 nodes. There is an edge between node 1 and node 2, node 3 and node 4,  node 2 and node 5, node 3 and node 6. Is it possible to draw these nodes along with edges in excel? Please notice, there is no (x,y) co-ordinates of the nodes defined here.

Comment: Interesting problem, is it reasonable to visualise the nodes in a two-dimensional plane? I.e. is it feasible to plot them in a scatter plot?

Answer (score 1):

[NodeXL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NodeXL) is an Excel add-in that has a variety of layout options.

Some screenshots of it in use here:
[image: NodeXL Excel Ribbon]
[image: Example data in Excel]
[image: Rendered visualisation in document pane]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use yED, a freely available desktop application (and also web app, but with no option to import from Excel).

It will generate your graphs and is highly customizable.

https://www.yworks.com/products/yed